# How to calculate the derivative of Jacobian in drake?

Tags: drake

I have successfully created MPB (of type double) in drake and managed to calculate numerical Jacobian for specified point with [CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#ae2516569f5a2cc27e76ee0cc8b728746) method.

But now I am interested in derivative of Jacobian at the same point. Automatic differentiation seems to be appropriate tool for that.

So I converted my plant from double to AutoDiffXd, but could not succeeded in converting Context to AutoDiffXd.

[CreateDefaultContext](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_system.html#ad047317ab91889c6743d5e47a64c7f08) of autodiff plant goes into segmentation fault.

So, is there a possibility to calculate value of derivative of Jacobian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateDefaultContext` for MBP `AutoDiffXd` should definitely not seg fault.  If you have a minimal reproduction case, please submit an issue.

I do think your workflow should work.  For some of the most common queries which need to be high performance, we provide analytical derivatives (often what one actually wants is Jdotv, for instance).. so there is a chance that we have or will have a better workflow than the autodiff route depending on your specific use case.

Comment: That's right, the workflow of converting the plant to AutoDiffXd and then using CreateDefaultContext on the new plant to get a context on AutoDiffXd is correct. Was your plant part of a bigger Diagram? because in that case you need to convert the entire Diagram and ask the diagram to create the new context. As @Russ Tedrake mentioned, a code snippet would help.

Comment: If what you really want is Jdot times v, you can compute it with [CalcBiasForJacobianTranslationalVelocity](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/a88a446a945ac275fc499360c3c3f3440e9c2817/multibody/plant/multibody_plant.h#L1677).

Comment: Yes, my plant is a part of diagram. So i need to convert diagram to AutoDiffXd too and then take context from it?

Comment: Right. Once you have the whole Context<AutoDiffXd> you can extract the MBP's Context from that.

Comment: Finally, diagram wasn't required in the case, so i removed it from the code.
After a while I find the correct way of creating AutoDiffXd copy of a plant and context at: [kuka_iiwa_model_tests.h](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/c6f0525c9c9745a6e61461a176cd6a26a9582a74/multibody/plant/test/kuka_iiwa_model_tests.h)